# How can I make a named HTML file the default in a folder on the server?

Tags: html

There is an index.html which opens default page of a website/webpage, say, [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

In the root, there is a folder, say, UdG, which has a html file, say, UdG.html, containing only text.

Need that [www.domain.com/UdG](http://www.domain.com/UdG) opens the UdG.html.

What code lines to write in UdG.html and index.html?

Tried link `ref=` and a `href=` but [www.domain.com/UdG](http://www.domain.com/UdG) does not open UdG.html.

Comment: This is a server configuration thing, usually. You can set the default file for a folder in .htaccess, for example. Are you able to do that?

Comment: Of course, it's better to just name the second file index.html also, and then it's automatic.

Comment: Renamed to index.html and it opens. Thanks!

Comment: That's a web server configuration, not something that can be decided by your visitors. What setting to change depends on the software (Apache, Nginx, Caddy...).

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is part of the URL, like `www.domain.com/UdG/` and no file is indicated in the URL, the server will look for an `index.php` or `index.html` file inside that folder (in this order) and load it. That's true for any folder.

If there is no folder in the URL, the server will look for index.php and index.html on the root level and open that one.

So whatever you want to be opened automatically, rename it to index.html.